# Ubuntu 14.04 Switchable Graphics ATI Lenovo G510

Tags: 14.04, ati, graphics, gpu, integrated

Sorry if my question sound stupid, but I'm not very clever with linux yet

I'm facing well known problem around here namely **switchableGraphics**.

In [--here--](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/hybrid_graphics) you can find information that in linux kernel >= 3.12 switchableGraphics is managed by "system" and when I'm executing

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

it returns

```
0:DIS: :DynOff
1:IGD:+:Pwr
```

So it means that power supplied to discreteGPU (ATI 8570m) was tuned off (DynOff) by "system"(radeon driver) automatically. Ok so far .

My question is ... is it possible to use "automatic power managment" and switch to ATI gpu ?? I tried already vgaswitcheroo

```
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
echo ON > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
echo DIS > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

but **cat** returns

```
0:DIS: :DynOff
1:IGD:+:Pwr
```

Thanks in advance !!